# Error while building ionic 2 app with latest cli

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic-cli

Help! I'm desperate....can't get this fixed. Error while building, see below.

```
ionic cordova:build platform android --debug
TypeError: Cannot read property 'private' of undefined
at inputs.filter (\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\index.js:20826:31)
at Array.filter (native)
at BuildCommand.getCleanInputsForTelemetry (\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\index.js:20825:18)
at BuildCommand. (\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\index.js:20788:48)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\index.js:20731:58)
```

I tried updating different items already:

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
ionic platform update android@6.1.2
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

please help! Can't get my app to production!

Question: has anyone had this problem before, and knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that you have up to date versions of npm and node.

Then make sure that you have the latest version of Ionic (2.2)

To do this you should update your package.json file ..

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
}
```

Then delete your node_modules directory and then run:

npm install (or maybe sudo npm install)

This should update everything and hopefully solve the issue